# changing the bias parameter b in scikit SVM after training, before prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I'm using `sklearn.svm.SVC` for a classification problem. After having trained on my data, I would like to loop the bias (i.e. the term b in the usual sign(w.x + b) SVM equation) through a number of values, so as to produce an ROC curve. (I've already performed cross-validation and chosen my hyperparameters, so this is for testing).

I tried playing with the `.intercept_` attribute, but this doesn't change what I get out from `.predict()`... Is there an alternative method for altering the bias term?

I could potentially recover the support vectors, and then implement my own `.predict()` function, with an altered bias, but this seems like a rather heavy-handed approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a very same problem 2 years ago. Unfortunately the only solution is to do this by yourself. Implementing "predict" is pretty straight forward, it is a one-liner in Python. Unfortunately .intercept_ is actually a **copy** of intercept used internally (the libsvm one). Quite confusing thing is that for LinearSVC from the very same library it is not true, and you can actually alternate the bias (however, without access to kernels, obviously).

Obviously you do not have to go as deep as computing kernels values yourself. You still have access to "decision_function", which in the end, has a bias inside. Simply remove the old bias from decision function, add new one, and take the sign. This will be (up to the sign of bias):

```
def new_predict(clf, new_bias, X):
  return np.sign(clf.decision_function(X) + clf.intercept_ - new_bias)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think there is a small mistake here though... As I check the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#svm-mathematical-formulation), it says "the predicted class correspond to `decision_function`'s sign, so I guess the correct answer should be `return np.sign(clf.decision_function(X) - new_bias)`.

Comment: that is incorrect - you need to *remove the old bias*. That's what is written in the answer too.